# Random row value display in random place without duplicate value mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql

In a mysql table I have some 30 rows. want to display 1 random row data in 3 different places in a same page without duplicate the row.

Can any one help me regarding this?

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the post is unclear/too broad. It's missing code and details/schema etc.

Comment: why was this upvoted?

Comment: It was upvoted because it was very helpful, and clear, and showed lots of research ;) /sarcasm

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It's a sign that the OP has friends here.

Comment: @IncredibleHat *lol!* yeah... I got the latter part of it ;-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Prolly; that or a few sock puppets they like to play with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this? Each array_pop() would remove a value from the array, so you would never get the same value twice.

```
// Get your data into an array (since there's only 30 rows):
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3;");
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

// Randomise the array:
shuffle($rows);

// Get first random value:
$row = array_pop($rows);
print ($row['value']);

// Get second random value:
$row = array_pop($rows);
print ($row['value']);

// etc...
```

Comment: Good luck with this, but why the `mysql_` api? that's in deprecation/deletion as of php 7; did you know that?

Comment: Thanks for the useful feedback guys, I've changed it to use the mysqli_ functions.

Comment: Just replacing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` isn't really enough. You should check the manual for the differences in the API calls.

Comment: I edited your post; adding the db connection argument. @rangfu and the missing `I` for `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.

Comment: Looking forward to your edit then @MagnusEriksson :-)

Comment: Micro-optimize that 30 row table query by adding `LIMIT 3` to it ;)

Comment: Not needed. @FunkFortyNiner sorted it out :-) This is like tag team-edits.

Comment: Thanks @IncredibleHat, have added that!

Comment: So many edits, my browser had fits =D

Comment: I'll upvote; why not. Looks ok to *moi.*

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Team effort can be a good thing at times ;-)